# is there a better way of deleting a block of code?

Tags: cut-copy-paste, normal-mode

I often use `da{dd` to delete a whole block of code.

[image]

if a block of code is within paragraph, `dap` works really nicely.

I tried some function text objects plugins for Javascript but didn't have much success.

Any way of making this work like a text object?

Comment: I guess, I just thought I could add a normal mode map `noremap dac da{dd`

Comment: Isn't `di{` enough?

Comment: Di{ will not delete the current line. The method definition

Comment: Oh, should've watched the full screencast.:-]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `onoremap` suggested by Ingo works, but, ultimately what I wanted was to create a custom text object. The downside to the `onoremap` is that I can't use it for visual selection.  I ended up installing a custom text object plugin called [vim-textobj-chunk](https://github.com/Chun-Yang/vim-textobj-chunk) for this and really happy with it.

Answer (score 8):

You can turn the *characterwise* `a{` text object into a *linewise* by prepending a `V`, as in `dVa{`. This way, the stuff with the block is removed as well, and you don't need to issue another `dd`.

You can easily turn this into your own custom text object, e.g.: `ab`, and then use this as `dab`, `cab`, and so on:

```
onoremap ab Va{
```

Comment: This sounds exactly what I was looking for! Creating my custom text object. but `ddVa{` doesn't work for me in the same way that `da{dd`

Comment: your `onoremap` does work, just not prepended by v visual (`vab`), because its a Operator pending mapping, it only works with `c`,`d`,`y`. http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/intro.html#Operator-pending

Comment: Thank you very much. This saved my day! I have known about `ya{` and its friends for long, but I have never figured out how to change a character text object to a line text object (I don't even know the correct term to search for) and just ended up using visual mode instead most of the time.